# Retrieve the current dimensions of the AbsoluteLayout after adding images outside its bounds

Tags: .net, maui

I'm using an AbsoluteLayout with a ScrollView to create a canvas on which I place images. The AbsoluteLayout has automatic dimensions, and when I add an image outside its current bounds, it expands with the ScrollView, allowing me to scroll to the image. However, when I debug to retrieve the current width of the AbsoluteLayout, it remains the same as at the beginning.

I want to retrieve the current dimensions of the AbsoluteLayout after adding images outside its bounds. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you mean you want to get the height and width of the AbsoluteLayout?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the current Width and Height values. I inserted an image at position X=1500, Y=1500 in the ScrollView with the AbsoluteLayout extending. However, upon verification, the Width and Height values remain unchanged

Comment: When you put the picture in the AbsoluteLayout, it will change the position and size of children in an AbsoluteLayout. You should get the height and width of the elements which in the AbsoluteLayout.

Comment: I want to get the height and width of an absolutelayout after its enlargement

Comment: You can write the method to get the width and height of the `AbsoluteLayout` after you put the image in it. You need to name the AbsoluteLayout then get the height and width of it.